# Difference between '_' and '/' when loading classes?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, autoloader

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference? Or if they're equals, but one is "righter" than the other one?

For example: I've seen something like `namespace_module/helper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part `namespace_module` as the alias for your blocks, models, helpers you define in your `config.xml`

```
<blocks>
    <namespace_module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
    </namespace_module>
    ...
```

The second part after the slash gives you the exact block/model/helper of your extensions. The `/` *replaces* the class type (`_Block_`, `_Model_`, ...)   you want to load.

For your example `namespace_module/helper` it means Magento should load (in case of a block) `Namespace_Module_Block_Helper`.

Same for models and helper classes ...

```
some_module/some_other_stuff
```

... will load ...

```
Some_Module_Model_Some_Other_Stuff
```